# How to create a dynamic size int in C?

Tags: c, dynamic-typing

I would like to create a variable that could store an integer of a variable size, the variable should be able to resize itself as needed.

```c
dyn_int num = 42;
// sizeof(num) == sizeof(char)
num = 1000;
// sizeof(num) == sizeof(short)
num = 99999;
// sizeof(num) == sizeof(int)
num = 9999999999;
// sizeof(num) == sizeof(long)
```

Note that I'm perfectly fine with having to use functions everywhere like that:

```c
dyn_int num = init_dyn_int(42);
// sizeof(num) == sizeof(char)
num = new_dyn_int(&num, 1000);
```

Note also that I'm perfectly fine with for example `sizeof(num)` being a bit bigger than `sizeof(char)` (to store some metadata for example).

Comment: Do you want to also be able to set it to numbers like 9999999999999999999999?

Comment: That would be a cool bonus, but definitely not a priority.

Comment: It's hard to imagine this will buy you anything.  My hunch is that the performance of the code you're looking for — on the metrics of speed, space, programmer effort, reliability, and bugfreeness — will be significantly worse than straightforward code that simply but "wastefully" uses `long` everywhere.

Comment: There's no C type that can change its size like this.  The best you could do would be to have `num` be a pointer to a `malloc`'ed region, and then use `realloc` to change its size.  (Note that you'd then have 4 or 8 bytes for the pointer, and also that `malloc` usually rounds allocated sizes up to some minimum quantum also., so you couldn't possibly save any space overall.)

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @SteveSummit That was my hunch too. I was still wondering if there were some alternatives to having a `void *` (already 8 bytes) and `malloc`/`realloc` for everything. But alright, it seems that it's not worth having this system.

Comment: @klutt it was to save memory. But it seems there is no way to make it worth.

Comment: You may be looking for an [Arbitrary Precision Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) Library. Something like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) may suit. GMP also happens to be [open source](https://github.com/alisw/GMP) so you can see how its implemented

Comment: It's very unlikely you will be able to save a substantial amount of memory with this method. Most likely the overhead will eat it all up. And it will greatly complicate your code for little gain.

Comment: Realize that some types are 8 bytes on your system for a reason. The reason being that your CPU is capable of handling such data in a single instruction. Whereas smaller, misaligned types might actually be harder to handle since extra overhead code might be needed. So what you gain in RAM size you lose in execution speed and program size. In general, don't attempt "clever" manual optimization unless you have in-depth knowledge of C and the target hardware both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such thing in C.

The closest you can get, is to have a pointer to an array of digits, and then if you run out of digits you can allocate a new array with more digits. This is what libraries like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) do.

But the pointer is 8 bytes big, so if your numbers all fit in 8 bytes, you might as well just use 8-byte numbers directly.

Comment: ... and `sizeof` will not report on the number of digits currently allocated.  Also, the digits don't need to be base-10.  Base 256 (or 65536, *etc*) would be more natural and convenient.